# october cms linking another page into a page

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I am trying to add link to static page

```
 `<a href='{{ "administer/catalog-items_item"|page({ item_id: item.id })  }}'>test             
   </a>`
```

when I click on test it clicked URL its not working correctly, it seems twig is not parsing static page content. or more likely static page is not using twig engine to parse its code.

is there any way to work this out? how can I add dynamic link generated by twig to static page content.

Comment: can you share where do you writing this link code :), because it seems twig is not parsing it correctly

Comment: @HardikSatasiya i passed this in my static page.

Comment: can you share screenshot how you are doing it so i can try to make it work may be ..

Comment: @HardikSatasiya added screenshot on top please take a look and help me.

Comment: updated `#Dynamic Links using property` check this section for dynamically passing value to snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not add `twig markup` into the `static page` content.

> However if you want ot use `twig markup` you can use it using snippets.

Let me show you, how you can add that dynamic link using snippet.

1. Create snippet
2. Add snippet to the your static page

> **1. Create snippet**

[image]

**OR just use code and add it**

> file : /themes/your_theme/partials/static-snippet.htm

```html
description = "test snippet"

[viewBag]
snippetCode = "test-snippet"
snippetName = "Test Snippet"
==
<a href={{ "ajax"|page }}> click me </a>
```

**Note :** please change code according to your need. `<a href='{{"administer/catalog-items_item"|page({ item_id: item.id }) }}'>test</a>`

for your item id you need to make variable which id you want to show in snippet. or from partial add component and get it from there there.

> **2. Add snippet to the your static page**

[image]

**OR just use code and add it**

> file : /themes/your_theme/content/static-pages/static-page.htm

```html
[viewBag]
title = "static-page"
url = "/static-page"
is_hidden = 0
navigation_hidden = 0
==
<figure data-snippet="test-snippet">&nbsp;</figure>
```

**Note :** here you just need to use `<figure data-snippet="test-snippet">&nbsp;</figure>` and paste it where you need to show link.

### #Dynamic Links using property

> **1. Add property**

[image]

> **Code**

```html
description = "test snippet"

[viewBag]
snippetCode = "test-snippet"
snippetName = "Test Snippet"
snippetProperties[itemId][title] = "Item Id"
snippetProperties[itemId][type] = "string"
snippetProperties[itemId][default] = ""
snippetProperties[itemId][options][] = ""
==
<a href={{ "param"|page({ id: itemId }) }}> click me {{itemId}} </a>
```

> **2. Click ok snippet and add desired value. and then again add new snippet and add new value as much as you like**

[image]

> **Code**

```html
[viewBag]
title = "static-page"
url = "/static-page"
is_hidden = 0
navigation_hidden = 0
==
<figure data-inspector-id="inspectorid-447952244549" data-property-itemid="10" data-snippet="test-snippet">&nbsp;</figure>
```

---

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: the thing is i want to add multiple links in a page so should i add all in snippent and then use that snippent is that possible?

Comment: like i said you can just add parameter in snippet and use like that give me 2 mins let me post that solution as well